# How to use ReplaceAll on an expression that contains a rule

Tags: replacement

I know I have seen this before but can't seem to locate it today.

I am trying to take an expression that has some rules in it and replace one of that parts that contain a rule using `ReplaceAll`

For a simple example consider:

```
testExpression = {"stuff", Axes -> {False, True}}
(* {"stuff", Axes -> {False, True}} *)
```

and I want to replace the

```
Axes -> {False, True}
```

with

```
Axes -> False
```

I have tried

```
testExpression /. 
 Hold[Axes -> {False, True}] -> Hold[Axes -> False]
(* {"stuff", Axes -> {False, True}} *)
```

as well as

```
testExpression /. 
 Hold[Rule[Axes , {False, True}]] -> Hold[Rule[Axes , False]]
(* {"stuff", Axes -> {False, True}} *)
```

I promise to add this to my set of notes if someone could kindly enlighten me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a couple possibilities:

```
testExpression /. Rule[Axes, {False, True}] -> Axes -> False
testExpression /. HoldPattern[Axes -> {False, True}] -> Axes -> False
```

> {"stuff", Axes -> False}
>
> {"stuff", Axes -> False}

Answer (score 5):

I think this is just a matter of getting the parentheses right

```
testExpression /. (Axes -> {False, True}) -> (Axes -> False)
(* {"stuff", Axes -> False} *)
```

Comment: I'd have posted this too. (+1)

Comment: Wish I could accept them both